# Jquery add value to an array if does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the  following function which supposed to add a value to an array if does not exist.

```
    var category_json = new Array();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Reports/appointment_distribution_by_group/",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {county: county, sub_county: sub_county, facility: facility, date_from: date_from, date_to: date_to},
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Populate series
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 /* Values returned from variable data as data[i].group_name = > Adolescents,Adolescents,All,All,ART Clients,ART Clients,ART Clients,ART Clients,Lactating woman,New Clients,New Clients,Paeds on ART,Paeds on ART,PMTCT,PMTCT */                               
                            if(jQuery.inArray(data[i].group_name,category_json)!== -1) {
                                //element exists in array
                                console.log(" Found ..." + data[i].group_name);
                            } else {
                                //element not found in array
                                category_json.push([data[i].group_name]);
                                console.log("Not Found ..."+data[i].group_name);
                                console.log(category_json);
                            }

                        }
                        var type = jQuery.type(category_json);
                        alert(category_json);
                        alert(type);
                        // draw chart

                    }, error: function (errorThrown) {

                    }});
```

I want to add the returned values to the  category json array , but only unique values . However , the checking of the  value in the  array does not return a true at all. 
Which condition should I use to check if the value exists in the  array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You push the element to the array in another array

your code `category_json.push([data[i].group_name]);`

should be like this `category_json.push(data[i].group_name);`

**Example:**

```js
var arr = [1, 2];

arr.push([3]);

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, [3]]
```

after that you check like this `arr.indexOf(3)` and this always return -1